# GET ActionResult is successful on live server, but not JsonResult (works on localhost)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I have an MVC app. Inside the home controller are two actions (actually, there are more than that, but it doesn't matter). Here's what they look like:

```
public ActionResult Contact(){
  return View();
}

public JsonResult KeepSession(){
  HttpContext.Session["timeVal"] = DateTime.Now;
  return new JsonResult() { Data = "Success" };  
}
```

These both work splendidly from `localhost:0000/Home/Contact` and `localhost:0000/Home/KeepSession`. I can GET and POST to both of them using JavaScript, which is perfect, because that's exactly what I want to do with KeepSession.

Here's the problem: I cant GET or POST to `deployedurl.com/Home/KeepSession`, but I can GET or POST to `deployedurl.com/Home/Contact`.

Any thoughts? I've tried KeepSession with an [HttpPost] attribute and without. I don't really care if I post or get. I can access the Contact action, so I don't think it's a routing issue.

Comment: have you looked at the console for the error

Comment: Try this appraoch  return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)  instead of return new JsonResult().

Comment: I'm getting no errors on the server, and Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) only works on localhost, so there's no difference there. :/

Comment: what http response are you getting for `KeepSession`?

Comment: Hi Brandon, I'm getting a 404.

Comment: show your javascript